# Get hashtags from .CSV and count them in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, csv

So, I want to extract a list with a counter of all the hashtags in the "Description" column. Description is made by text + hashtags and is a column in a .csv file written before.

Ex. If my descs are:

It was great! #sunny #day #great

Thanks for all guys! #thanks #sunny

I'm expecting something like this: [ #sunny: 2, #day: 1, #great: 1, #thanks: 1 ] And how can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
from tiktok_bot import TikTokBot  # API
import csv
import datetime
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import os 
import re    #I was trying something with Regex


try:
     os.mkdir("./data")
except OSError as e:
   print("Directory exists")


def getData():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")

def buildFileName(type):
    return ("./data/") + getData() + (type) + ".csv"

bot = TikTokBot()

my_feed = bot.list_for_you_feed(count=5)

print (Fore.CYAN + str(len(my_feed)), Fore.RED + "posts found")
print (Style.RESET_ALL) 

most_shared_posts = [post for post in my_feed if post.statistics.share_count > 2_000]

print (Fore.CYAN + str(len(most_shared_posts)), Fore.RED + "topshare posts found")
print (Style.RESET_ALL)

with open(buildFileName("_shares"), mode='a') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['User ID', 'URL', 'Description', 'Comments', 'Likes']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for post in most_shared_posts:
        print(str(post.author_user_id) , str(post.share_url) , str(post.desc) , post.statistics.comment_count , post.statistics.digg_count)
        writer.writerow({'User ID': str(post.author_user_id), 'URL': str(post.share_url), 'Description': str(post.desc), 'Comments': post.statistics.comment_count, 'Likes': post.statistics.digg_count})

hashtags = (['Description']).count(1) # here comes the problems
re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtags)
print(hashtags)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear why you're pulling the hashtags out after you've written the csv file, rather than as you go along. Also, your `hashtags = (['Description']).count(1)` line looks like it probably doesn't do what you want (your regex looks fine to me). How about something like:

```
hashtagregex = re.compile(r"#(\w+)")
hashtags = dict()
for post in most_shared_posts:
    print(str(post.author_user_id) , str(post.share_url) , str(post.desc) , post.statistics.comment_count , post.statistics.digg_count)
    writer.writerow({'User ID': str(post.author_user_id), 'URL': str(post.share_url), 'Description': str(post.desc), 'Comments': post.statistics.comment_count, 'Likes': post.statistics.digg_count})
    posttags = hashtagregex.findall(str(post.desc))
    for tag in posttags:
        if tag in hashtags:
            hashtags[tag] += 1
        else:
            hashtags[tag] = 1
print(hashtags)
```

The `hashtags` dict should have what you want in it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Takes the list of the values from `Description` and determines the count

```
counts = dict()
def counting(items):
    lWords = ''.join(items).split(" ")
    for i in lWords:
        if(i[0]=="#"):
            counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
    return counts
```

change column into list, and null values are not included in the list

```
items = [x for x in df['Description'].tolist() if pd.notnull(x)]
print(counting(items))
```